# How to fallback for webp to jpg with amp-img?

Tags: amp-html

I use webp with fallback for jpg like:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img/my.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="img/my.jpg">
</picture>
```

But the `<picture>` tag are forbidden im AMP.
How can I handle to use webp with fallback to jpg?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by defining a fallback image inside the `amp-img`:

```
<amp-img alt="Mountains"
  width="550"
  height="368"
  src="images/mountains.webp">
  <amp-img alt="Mountains"
    fallback
    width="550"
    height="368"
    src="images/mountains.jpg"></amp-img>
</amp-img>
```

https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-img#example:-specifying-a-fallback-image